# Python flask: Extracted HTML won't load correctly as is

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

So I have code that allows me to visit any website I want via URL while "invisible". You can get to my domain here: "sm--supermechm500.repl.co/home/ViewWindow". Try typing in "http://youtube.com/". (It's invisible because you can't return to the website through your history). You will notice that the website appears to be broken. All I did was take the HTML of the page and re-render it exactly the way it is, except for title tag.

## Why does the page appear to be broken, if none of the code was modified? Does Flask not recognize some of the HTML it receives?

Here is the python code in question:

```
@web_site.route('/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def ViewWindowResult():
  urlboi = request.values.get('url') # received through form
  try:
    response = urllibrequest.urlopen(urlboi)
  except Exception: # attempts to open url
    raise ValueError

  retries = 20
  while retries <= 20:
      try:
        htmlBytes = response.read()
      except Exception: # attempts to read and retries if failed
        retries =- 1
        continue
      else:
        break

  if retries > 0:
    htmlstr = htmlBytes.decode("utf8")
    soupedhtmlstr = BeautifulSoup(htmlstr)
    sortedhtmlstr = soupedhtmlstr.prettify() # make sure code is nested correctly
    sortedhtmlstr = sortedhtmlstr.replace('<head>', '<head><title>ViewWindow - Result</title>') # replace original title with "ViewWindow - Result"
    return sortedhtmlstr 
  else: # if retries is exhausted, end attempt and lead to 500 error.
     raise ValueError
```

Also any change suggestions appreciated.

Comment: youtube uses relative urls for CSS and JS files - without domain `http://youtube.com/` - so later when web browser loads HTML from your server then it tries to get these CSS/JS files from your server, not from youtube, and it can't find them on your server. You would have to check all urls in HTML and add `http://youtube.com/` - it means urls in tags <a>, <link>, <script>, <img>, etc. Problem can be with urls used in JavaScript code or generated by JavaScript.

Comment: @furas I would need to use BeautifulSoup for that...?

Comment: you can try with `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml` or any module which can create/edit `HTML/XML`. Eventually you can use `htmlstr` and use string's functions to search and replace text, or regex but with `BeautifulSoup` could be easier.